# Open another webpage, logging in through code Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to be able to login to an external domain webpage through code, and give the resultant page to user.

Tried using HttpWebRequest,
The user agent that makes the request must support JavaScript. The HttpWebRequest doesn’t support JavaScript.

Also found some suggestions about using WebBrowser Control, but that is for Forms apps.

Need some solution for ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: At the end of the day the javascript or whatever happens in the page makes an HTTP request sending the username and password to the server, right? It's this HTTP request that you could simulate with `HttpWebRequest`. You don't need to be executing any javascript. Go get Fiddler and capture the actual HTTP request. Now you can make the same.

Comment: Thanks Darin, it is a complicated request, with SSL verification first, only cookie data is passed, and i don't see any parameter in the request that seems like the username and password.